# Numbering a octahedron

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorial-geometry

> In the following figure, on the left, it is represented in an o.n.
> Oxyz, a regular octahedron [ABCDEF], whose vertices belong to the
> coordinated axes. Assume that the [ABC] face of the octahedron is
> numbered with the number 1, as shown in the figure on the right.
> It is intended to number the octahedron's remaining faces with
> numbers from 2 to 8 (a different number in each face).
>
> [image]
>
> How many different ways
> can the remaining seven faces be numbered, so that, after the
> octahedron have all the faces numbered, at least three of the
> concurrent faces at vertex **A** are numbered with odd numbers?

I've tried to solve this problem with the following reasoning:

$${}^{3}\textrm{C}_{2}*(^{3}\textrm{P}_{2})*5! = 2160$$

Where:

- ${}^{3}\textrm{C}_{2}$ is the number of ways we can select the 2 faces that will have odd numbers from the 3 faces that are concurrent at vertex A;
- $_{}^{3}\textrm{P}_{2}$ are the possibilities of choosing 2 of the 3 odd numbers available (3,5,7) to number the 2 faces that need to be concurrent at vertex A;
- 5! that is the numbers of ways we can then number the 5 left faces with the 5 numbers that are remain.

However, I can't understand why my answer is wrong. The correct answer to this problem is **1872**, given with the reasoning of:

> $$3!*4! + 4*3*(_{}^{3}\textrm{P}_{2})*4!=1872$$ In which:
>
> - $3!*4!$ is the numbers of ways in which all of the 4 faces that are concurrent at vertex A have odd numbers;
> - $4*3*(_{}^{3}\textrm{P}_{2})*4!$ is the numbers of ways in which 3 of the 4 faces that are concurrent at vertex A have odd numbers:
>
>   - $4$ are the four even numbers available (2,4,6,8)
>   - $3$ are the numbers of faces that can have the even numbers at the top of the octahedron;
>   - $_{}^{3}\textrm{P}_{2}$ are the possibilities of choosing 2 of the 3 odd numbers available (3,5,7) to number the 2 faces that need to
>     be concurrent at vertex A;
>   - $4!$ that is the number of ways we can then number the 4 left faces with the 4 numbers that remain.

Even though I could understand the solution to this problem, I still don't know why mine is wrong. I am assuming I am counting extra scenarios (since $2160>1872$), but which one's?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  This is a very well-posed question for a first posting.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you! :)

Comment: What does " o.n. Oxyz" means? I only find references of this in portuguese.

Comment: @jjagmath "Orthonormal Referential" (Referencial Ortonormado), with center in O and containing the X,Y,Z axes - But well spotted! The problem is in fact translated from portuguese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula counts the cases where all four faces are labeled with odds numbers $3$ times each, once for each pair of odd numbers $>1$.  So, you need to subtract twice the number of such labelings.  The offical solutions shows that there are $144$ such labelings, and indeed $$2160-288=1872$$

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! :)

Comment: @DiogoSousa My pleasure.